# ReactJS - How to Prevent ContextTypes from being altered

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have two context types: (1) productsContexts & (2) rangeContext.

rangeContext is nothing more than preset ranges from a json file so as to group the products according to each respective range.

> Below is an illustration of a side-box component that groups products
>   according to those preset ranges and it also illustrates the problem:

[image]

**The first visit to that page, everything works fine, but click off and then re-visit the page and the previous data remains and then doubles itself, 3rd time, it is triple, and so on.**

I did nothing with the rangeContext data but pass it along to a local variable for mapping data manipulation. I did not save anything to the context itself.

Here is what I have tried to do to solve this problem; all have failed:

1. I passed the rangeContext to state first, then on componentWillUnmount, I initialized state.
2. I Object.assign() the rangeContext to the local variable instead of directly passing the context to the local variable.
3. I took the context completely out of this component and used it in it's parent, and passed it to this component as props.

Nothing is working. While the hard data does not change, the range component never gets initialized on unmount and revisiting the page just carries forward what was in the range in the last visit and adds to it.

I know I probably did not do a great job explaining, but I know the problem is related to the context and I sure do not want to hit the database again, as I already did that for an earlier component.

Does anyone recognize the problem and have a solution?

Thanks

---

**UPDATE:**

I moved contextTypes for ranges out of the side-box component. 
Using redux flux, I dispatched for the range-actions in side-box's parent and passed the ranges to side-box as props. The problem went away, but I am not happy. I need someone to tell me why this is the right things to do, as ...

1. I had already called range-actions in a previous component, so why not put it in contextTypes instead of calling redux again?
2. Where as I only had 3 lines of code on side box, I have the same amount of code lines since now I am calling propTypes, but now I also have 
   MORE LINES of code in the parent calling redux, something I had already done for the range data in a previous component.

> **I would greatly appreciate someone telling me if I am still doing this**
>   **all wrong, or why it is right I had to add 26 more REDUNDANT lines of**
>   **code calling redux flux?**

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me what's wrong, but using `context` for this kind of data is a red flag. Can you elaborate on why you chose to use `context` for this kind of data?

Comment: What would you propose instead? Hitting the db again? Passing the data as props from parent nodes many, many levels above?

Comment: No, without knowing anything about your app, I would recommend using a shared service to house the information. This can be done simply with a method that returns a promise or observable (that resolves to the cached version if it has already been fetched) or using something like a "store" in Flux and similar models. But take a look at the [React docs for context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html): "Most applications will never need to use context". You're doing something every app needs to do. It's definitely not a good use case for context.

Comment: Can you paste a small example that reproduces your issue on JSBin or something? It seems to me as you're reusing the same object and just incrementing certain things within it. If you notice the `N/A` category doubles for each consecutive visit.

Comment: If I could I would but it is soooooooooooooo involved. The N/A category is a catch all in the "groupItemsToRanges" function and not in the context (initially). This really pisses me off because I am duplicating code and I do not know why I cannot use contextTypes because it seems to lose the initial values for ranges. The bottom line I have is why is contextTypes so bad as it only requires a few lines of code, and why does it not re-initialize back to it's orignal values when the component re-mounts?

Comment: Can you post some code? I'm not sure I understand where the redundancy is.